# How to simplify the plus action on boost variant?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-variant

I have boost variant type definition:

```
typedef boost::variant< bool, int, float, double> VariantType;
```

I want to implement add/subtract/multiply/divide action on it. Take Add class for example. The problem is if adding a new type into **VariantType**, such as std::string, The Add class must be updated with the new type.

```
struct Add : public boost::static_visitor<VariantType> {
    template <typename T>
    T operator() (T a, T b) const {
        return a + b;
    }
    float operator() (int a, float b) const {
        return a + b;
    }
    float operator() (float a, int b) const {
        return a + b;
    }
    double operator() (int a, double b) const {
        return a + b;
    }
    double operator() (double a, int b) const {
        return a + b;
    }
    double operator() (float a, double b) const {
        return a + b;
    }
    double operator() (double a, float b) const {
        return a + b;
    }
    VariantType operator() (bool a, int b) const {
        throw std::invalid_argument("bool and int can't Plus");
    }
    VariantType operator() (bool a, float b) const {
        throw std::invalid_argument("bool and float can't Plus");
    }
    VariantType operator() (bool a, double b) const {
        throw std::invalid_argument("bool and double can't Plus");
    }
    VariantType operator() (int a, bool b) const {
        throw std::invalid_argument("int and bool can't Plus");
    }
    VariantType operator() (float a, bool b) const {
        throw std::invalid_argument("float and bool can't Plus");
    }
    VariantType operator() (double a, bool b) const {
        throw std::invalid_argument("double and bool can't Plus");
    }
};
```

usage:

```
VariantType v1 = 1;
VariantType v2 = 2.1;
VariantType v3 = boost::apply_visitor(Add(), v1, v2);
cout<<boost::get<double>(v3)<<endl; //Print 2.2
```

The GCC version is 4.8.2; The boost version is 1.57.0;
How to simply the Add class? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make it a polymorphic functor:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d52ce57f8fc5973)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using VariantType = boost::variant<int, float, double, bool>;

struct Add : public boost::static_visitor<VariantType> {
    template <typename T, typename U>
    auto operator() (T a, U b) const -> decltype(a+b) { return a + b; }

    template <typename T> VariantType operator()(bool, T) const { throw std::invalid_argument("Can't to bool"); }
    template <typename T> VariantType operator()(T, bool) const { throw std::invalid_argument("Can't add bool"); }
    VariantType                     operator()(bool,bool) const { throw std::invalid_argument("Can't add bools"); }
};

int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;

    VariantType specimens[] = { int(42), 3.14f, 3.14, true };
    for (auto lhs : specimens)
        for (auto rhs : specimens)
        {
            try {
                std::cout << lhs << " + " << rhs << " ==  " << boost::apply_visitor(Add{}, lhs, rhs) << "\n";
            } catch(std::exception const& e) {
                std::cout << lhs << " + " << rhs << " ==> " << e.what() << "\n";
            }
        }
}
```

Prints:

```
42 + 42 ==  84
42 + 3.14 ==  45.14
42 + 3.14 ==  45.14
42 + true ==> Can't add bool
3.14 + 42 ==  45.14
3.14 + 3.14 ==  6.28
3.14 + 3.14 ==  6.28
3.14 + true ==> Can't add bool
3.14 + 42 ==  45.14
3.14 + 3.14 ==  6.28
3.14 + 3.14 ==  6.28
3.14 + true ==> Can't add bool
true + 42 ==> Can't to bool
true + 3.14 ==> Can't to bool
true + 3.14 ==> Can't to bool
true + true ==> Can't add bools
```

Comment: I just added a live example with many small fixes/clarifications /cc @DanielSchepler