# boost::variant - simplest way to apply arithmetic on variants

Tags: c++, math, boost, boost-variant

recently I have been experimenting with `boost::variant`. I am attempting to apply arithmetic to two variant objects of types `<int, float>` as such:

```
typedef boost::variant<int, float> VariableValue;
VariableValue var1 = 2;
VariableValue var2 = 5;
VariableValue var3 = var1 + var2;
std::cout << "Result: " << var3 << std::endl; //expected 7
```

This should work for either alternative of the variant such as:

```
VariantValue var1 = 2;
VariantValue var2 = 1.234;
VariantValue var3 = var1 + var2;
std::cout << "Result: " << var3 << std::endl; //expected 3.234
```

However this approach is not working. I have been researching this issue and I have seen people using `boost::apply_visitor` and `template` to achieve similar results. How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: Which alternative a variant holds is a run-time property. What type should `variant<A, B> + variant<C, D>` have?

Comment: The variant will hold either one depending on how to user specifies their input. I will update the question to reflect this.

Comment: Type of `var1 + var2` should be known at compile-time. But what a variant holds is known at run-time only. The compiler has to consider all possible alternatives. In the general case, the sum variant would consist of `N^2` types if you want to handle all possible combinations. The return type of a visitor cannot depend on which alternative a variant holds.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59279624/how-do-i-solve-template-argument-deduction-substitution-failure-when-implement/59280029#59280029).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution from the question [How to simplify the plus action on boost variant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38064895/how-to-simplify-the-plus-action-on-boost-variant) and simplified it for my purpose:

```
struct Add : public boost::static_visitor<VariableValue> {
    template <typename T, typename U>
    auto operator() (T a, U b) const -> decltype(a + b) {
        return a + b;
    }
};
```

To add:

```
VariantValue var1 = 2;
VariantValue var2 = 1.234;
std::cout << "Result: " << boost::apply_visitor(Add{}, var1, var2) << std::endl;
```

Outputs 3.234